# Deploy symfony project to FTP ipage

Tags: symfony

this my first time that I am going to deploy symfony 3.3 project to Ipage server side .. anyone can help me with the instructions that i should follow to host my website .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow this instruction for shared hosting

- copy your project to public_html
- clear cache
- connect to MySQL
- add .htaccess

Comment: Thanks alot :D that helped me alot and it works now :D